# Program the Arduino Due with the ESP32

Tags: arduino-due, esp32

I'm trying to do OTA firmware updates for the Arduino Due with the ESP32.
Now so far I'm able to get the firmware from a website and transfer it over UART.

Now I'm looking to get the firmware and upload it to the Arduino due. My understanding is that I have to write it at 0x00080000 and from there I can write al the binary information.

The problem is that I have no idea how to:

1. Get the Arduino DUE in programming mode
2. Write to the Arduino DUE (which pins to use, what protocol...)

Can someone give me some pointers as to where to start with this? I have been reading through the documentation of the SAM3x8e, but I don't get any wiser.

Comment: reset it over reset pin (with the "double reset") to enter the bootloader. then you can do a serial upload

Comment: @Juraj I can't seem to find any documentation on this. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: sorry my first comment doesn't apply for Due. Here is something about reset and upload: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue#toc14

Comment: Thank you for that. So from what I get now is that have to open the native USB port at 1200 baud, to get it into flash programming mode (or hold the reset down). Then the only thing I have to do is to send the bytes directly to the Arduino?

Comment: https://playground.arduino.cc/Bootloader/DueBootloaderExplained/